# How to assign values in a matrix element-by-element based on subscripts?

Tags: r

I define 2 numeric vectors as follows:

```
> x <- c(1,2)
> y <- c(1,2)
```

Now I would like to have a 2x2 matrix filled by e.g. the addition of the elements of `x` and `y` based on their indices, so the end result should look like:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    3    4
```

To achieve this with nested for loops is trivial, but will not perform on very large data sets. Trying to vectorize this with e.g.

```
> z <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2)
> z[x,y] <- x + y
```

fails, because the `+` operator adds `x` and `y` as vectors before doing the assignment to `z`. Using explicit subscripting with indices `i` and `j` fails as well:

```
> i <- 1:2
> j <- 1:2
> z[i,j] <- x[i] + y[j]
> z
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    4    4
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want using vectorization/subscripting, or am I limited to nested for loops or one of the apply functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the `outer` function ?

```
outer(x,y,"+")
```

Which gives :

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    3    4
```

Comment: Excellent, I wasn't aware that you can use outer() with _any_ function. And just checked that it runs +/- 100 times faster than nested for loops (using simple addition of elements).